# how to disable high level menu (those that are builtin) on google glass

Tags: google-glass

Would like to hide all the applications that came with the glass such as Show viewfinder, 
Recognize, Take a picture, Google, Record video, Send message, Get Directions, Call.

I think the only way is to remove or uninstall their *.apk but not sure what their package name is and its behavior.  I hope google glass to add this feature to the setting to hide the app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

to get the names of the packages use this command

adb shell pm list packages

you will get the full package names when I saw Show Finder I thought one of my colleagues developed it then it turned out it is one of the default application :) , if are comfortable with loosing some data uninstall the applications and if it didnt behave normally do a factory reset

adb uninstall your.apps.package.name